# react-native-firebase not regognized after install firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm begining with react-native, i tried to install firebase, but i have an error, i added firebase in depencencies, and run npm install firebase, firebase are addes on node-module, but when i import it on my class, my app doesn't work and generate error

this is my class

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import React from 'react';
import {GiftedChat} from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import {View, ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';


export default class MyChat extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            messages:  [] ,
            loading: true,
            uniRef: null,
        };
    }




  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      messages: [
        {
          _id: 1,
          text:
            'Bonjour, vous êtes sur le chat  !',
          createdAt: new Date(),
          user: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 'React Native',
            avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any',
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  }
  onSend(messages = []) {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
    }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <GiftedChat
          messages={this.state.messages}
          onSend={messages => this.onSend(messages)}
          user={{
            _id: 1,
          }}
        />
      );
  }
}
```

this is list of my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
   "firebase": "^7.8.0",
   "react": "16.9.0",
   "react-native": "0.61.5",
   "react-native-firebase": "5.5.6",
   "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.11.3"
},
```

when i run react-native run-android, i had this error on y mobile device

```
error : exception in 
hostObject:: get(propName : RNFirebase):
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:Failed resolution of :Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp;
```

Comment: Did you tried `yarn cache clean` and reinstall eveything?

Comment: for npm, i reinstall nos js, it's work, but for firebase no, always the same problem, i execute npm install firebase, it addes on node_module but it cause error when i execute react-native run-android

Comment: i will edit my post with code and explain the problem

Comment: Can you post you android `build.gradle` file ?

Comment: There may be some problem with the dependencies involved. Changes in the app level build.gradle dependencies may work.